# Need to increase Timeout for URLFetch.Fetch(url)

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I have a Keynote API that I use to provide metrics for Week to Date, Month to Date, and Year to Date performance Metrics.  The Week to date responds quickly, Month to Date sometimes Times out, and Year to Date always times out due to server side calculations.

Is there any way to increase the Timeout for my Google Script?

```
var prods = Utilities.jsonParse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(json_api_url).getContentText());
```

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to get Google Apps Script to handle time-outs when performing repeated operations, but they don't apply in this case. You've got a single operation that just takes a long time.

You have no way to increase the timeout values for your google scripts.